# AngularUI ui-view content not visible in "View page source"?

Tags: angularjs, seo, angular-ui-router

I am using angularJS v1.2 and ui-router.
Everything is working perfectly fine. But there is an issue regarding the "View page source".

the `<div ui-view></div>` is empty in my page source, both in firefox and google chrome.
Can you please explain why is this happening? Am i missing something here?

Comment: If you are viewing the page source through CTRL+U or mouse right click, then you are not able to see the page source as DOM. You need to use Firebug for Firefox or Developer Console for Chrome to see the live DOM. You can get to it through pressing "F12" the keyboard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are viewing the page source through <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or mouse right click, then you are not able to see the page source as DOM. You need to use Firebug for Firefox or Developer Console for Chrome to see the live DOM. You can get to it through pressing **<kbd>F12</kbd>** the keyboard!